# How to do warping of shapefile in GeoTools

Tags: openjump

Can any body give me simple warping example in GeoTools?

I have non georeferenced shapefile with polygons and I need to georeference this shapefile by using warp technique.

Please help me.

Comment: what do you mean by warp? this is usually used with rasters not vectors (like shapefile).

Comment: our aim is to transform the shape file coordinates which has selected in to given geo referenced coordinates.

Comment: then you should look at http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html

Comment: hello iant i need to do warping process example done in the OPENJUMP software with vector data actually i need the logic to do this. could u suggest me.

Comment: Can't help - but I've fixed your tags if you don't want to use GeoTools